# Setting permission on folders and items of Document Library

Tags: permissions, powershell, groups, library

Suppose I create a group "XYZ" who has full control on site . I will break permission inheritance of rootfolders (from folder starting with A to J) inside document library "abc" and assign a "XYZ" group with full control permissions to those folders.

My questions are

1. Do other group having full control permission would still be able to access it ?
2. How to make those folders accessible only to XYZ group and not others having full   Control permissions.

Answer (score 6):

Those groups will not be able to access the folders if the permission for the folder is broken and only the group "XYZ" has permissions to the folder and rest all are removed.

**UPDATE**

Sample powershell code:

```
$folders = $list.Folders
foreach ($spFolder in $folders)
{   
    $PermissionLevel = "PermissionName" ;
    $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName];   
    $spFolder.BreakRoleInheritance($false);
    $roleAssignment = New-Object microsoft.sharepoint.SPRoleAssignment($group);
    $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
    $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);   
    $spFolder.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment);       
    $spFolder.Update();   
}
```

Comment: ok. how do I achieve it using powershell? other full control groups also wont have access to it?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Your code will break inheritance of all folders from list. I want to break from root level selective folders only

Comment: You need to add logic for that. The code simply demonstrates how to break permissions on a folder and add group to it. You should not rely on spoon feeding.

Comment: I tested it but it seems that it is still visible to other groups having full control